# Finish all jQuery Animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

How can I universally stop all jQuery animations in progress? Would I have to select all elements using `:animated` then `finish()`, or is there a more efficient function for this exact purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [stop( [queue ] [, clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method

Based on lack of details in question you could do

```
$(':animated').stop()
```

and include preferred arguments

or if you have a stored jquery reference to anything being animated use that